# JavaScript - moment lib date generation is different than input

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using the momentJS date library. I'm trying to create a date from a given string (`2019-05-22T07:00:00.000Z`) however, the generated date with `moment(dateStr)` differs from the input by 4 days:

That's the resulting moment object:

```
Moment {
  _isAMomentObject: true,
  _i: 2019-05-22T07:00:00.000Z,
  _isUTC: false,
  _pf: {
    empty: false,
    unusedTokens: [],
    unusedInput: [],
    overflow: -2,
    charsLeftOver: 0,
    nullInput: false,
    invalidMonth: null,
    invalidFormat: false,
    userInvalidated: false,
    iso: false,
    parsedDateParts: [],
    meridiem: null,
    rfc2822: false,
    weekdayMismatch: false
  },
  _locale: Locale {
    _calendar: {
      sameDay: '[Today at] LT',
      nextDay: '[Tomorrow at] LT',
      nextWeek: 'dddd [at] LT',
      lastDay: '[Yesterday at] LT',
      lastWeek: '[Last] dddd [at] LT',
      sameElse: 'L'
    },
    _longDateFormat: {
      LTS: 'h:mm:ss A',
      LT: 'h:mm A',
      L: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
      LL: 'MMMM D, YYYY',
      LLL: 'MMMM D, YYYY h:mm A',
      LLLL: 'dddd, MMMM D, YYYY h:mm A'
    },
    _invalidDate: 'Invalid date',
    ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
    _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/,
    _relativeTime: {
      future: 'in %s',
      past: '%s ago',
      s: 'a few seconds',
      ss: '%d seconds',
      m: 'a minute',
      mm: '%d minutes',
      h: 'an hour',
      hh: '%d hours',
      d: 'a day',
      dd: '%d days',
      M: 'a month',
      MM: '%d months',
      y: 'a year',
      yy: '%d years'
    },
    _months: [
      'January',   'February',
      'March',     'April',
      'May',       'June',
      'July',      'August',
      'September', 'October',
      'November',  'December'
    ],
    _monthsShort: [
      'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar',
      'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
      'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep',
      'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
    ],
    _week: { dow: 0, doy: 6 },
    _weekdays: [
      'Sunday',
      'Monday',
      'Tuesday',
      'Wednesday',
      'Thursday',
      'Friday',
      'Saturday'
    ],
    _weekdaysMin: [
      'Su', 'Mo',
      'Tu', 'We',
      'Th', 'Fr',
      'Sa'
    ],
    _weekdaysShort: [
      'Sun', 'Mon',
      'Tue', 'Wed',
      'Thu', 'Fri',
      'Sat'
    ],
    _meridiemParse: /[ap]\.?m?\.?/i,
    _abbr: 'en',
    _config: {
      calendar: [Object],
      longDateFormat: [Object],
      invalidDate: 'Invalid date',
      ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
      dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/,
      relativeTime: [Object],
      months: [Array],
      monthsShort: [Array],
      week: [Object],
      weekdays: [Array],
      weekdaysMin: [Array],
      weekdaysShort: [Array],
      meridiemParse: /[ap]\.?m?\.?/i,
      abbr: 'en'
    },
    _dayOfMonthOrdinalParseLenient: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)|\d{1,2}/
  },
  _d: 2019-05-26T07:00:00.000Z,
  _isValid: true,
  _z: null
}
```

As you can see the `_i` field symbolizing the input is on the 22nd whereas the generated date instance (`_d`) field is on the 26th. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can't reproduce it: https://jsfiddle.net/6yr0Lq7a/

Comment: To print out the value of a Moment, use .format(), .toString() or .toISOString().

let createdDate = moment(new Date()).utc().format();
let expirationDate = moment(createdDate).add(4, 'd');
console.log(expirationDate.format());
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>